# Wrapping elements with the same attribute

Tags: javascript, html

If I have a list of similar elements, such that:

```
<outer-container>
    <element attribute="x" />
    <element attribute="x" />
    .
    .
    .
    <element attribute="y" />
    <element attribute="z" />
</outer-container>
```

How can I wrap the elements with `attribute="x"` so they are within their own container?

```
<outer-container>
    <inner-container>
        <element attribute="x" />
        <element attribute="x" />
    </inner-container>
    .
    .
    .
</outer-container>
```

Comment: Could you clarify a little what you are trying to do? It's confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your HTML to make it easier to test.

```
<div>
    <input attribute="x" />
    <input attribute="x" />
    <p>divider</p>
    <input attribute="y" />
    <input attribute="z" />
</div>
```

Assuming you want all of the elements of that kind in one container, positioned where the first one was found, you can do this.

```
   // invoked like this
wrapAll('input[attribute=x]', 'span');
```

```
   // implemented like this
function wrapAll(selector, wrapper) {
    if (typeof wrapper === 'string')
        wrapper = document.createElement(wrapper);
    else if (!wrapper || !wrapper.nodeType)
        throw "Illegal 'wrapper' argument."

    var els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    els[0].parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, els[0]);

    for(var i = 0, len = els.length; i < len; i++)
        wrapper.appendChild(els[i]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5z2uA/4/

---

If you wanted different consecutive groups to be wrapped together, you can do this.

```
   // invoked like this
wrapAdjacent('input[attribute=x]', 'span');
```

```
   // implemented like this
function wrapAdjacent(selector, wrapper) {
    if (typeof wrapper === 'string')
        wrapper = document.createElement(wrapper);
    else if (!wrapper || !wrapper.nodeType)
        throw "Illegal 'wrapper' argument."

    var els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    for (var i = 0, len = els.length; i < len; ) {
        var this_wrapper = wrapper.cloneNode(false);
        els[i].parentNode.insertBefore(this_wrapper, els[i]);
        do {
            this_wrapper.appendChild(els[i]);
            i++;
        }
        while (nextEl(this_wrapper) === els[i])       
    }
}
function nextEl(el) {
    while (el && (el = el.nextSibling) && el.nodeType !== 1) {}
    return el;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5z2uA/5/

Answer (score 2):

If jQuery is an option:

```
$('[attribute="x"]').wrapAll('<inner-container/>');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/Hgp7B/